# Would "aftermath" ever be used to mean "a reaction of crackdown"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, poetry, poetic

In the context of revolution, there often comes the word "aftermath," usually meaning the bad consequences of a given revolution on the long run.

Can I, however, use it to mean the immediate reactions of crackdown revolutionaries often get from their state?

AN IMPORTANT clarification: I insist on the word "aftermath" because it contributes to a rhyming effect.

So I want my "thing" to sound like this:

". . . . . . . . . .

Squares replete with a revolution of wrath,

A revolution by those who fear no aftermath."

By "aftermath" I mean crackdown, injuries, deaths, homelessness, etc. In other words, I mean that the revolutionaries fear no such things. Simply put, they are brave.

Can I have your thoughts on my use of "aftermath?"

Comment: "Poetic" license.

Comment: @Elliott I like that! Does it make sense in the way I mean it?

Comment: I don't believe there is a lot of room for interpretation. By "aftermath" you mean "consequences", "reaction" and/or "reprisal".

Comment: You may be better off adding a word rhyming with *reprisal* after *wrath*, instead, so you can use *reprisal* in place of *aftermath*.

Answer (score 1):

Elliott Frisch is right that you can defend your choice of *aftermath* under poetic license, and JSB is correct that the actual meaning you seem to have in mind is closer to *reprisal* than to *aftermath*.

The argument I would make on behalf of your second line is that "who fear no aftermath" is simply a telescoping of a lengthier and more elaborate phrase such as "who fear no negative consequences in the struggle's aftermath" or perhaps "who fear no aftermath that they can imagine." Such telescoping may strain your readers' ability to grasp your intended meaning, but that is hardly an unusual trade-off in poetry.

By the way, *aftermath* is a rather unusual word in any case because its usual meaning today is so far afield from its original meaning. Here is a discussion of *aftermath* in John Ayto, *Arcade Dictionary of Word Origins* (1990):

> **aftermath** [16th century] Originally, and literally, an aftermath was a second crop of grass or similar grazing vegetation, grown after an earlier crop in the same season had been harvested. Already by the mid 17th century it had taken on the figurative connotations of 'resulting condition' which are today its only living sense. The *-math* element comes from Old English *mœth* 'mowing,' a noun descended from the Germanic base *mœ*, source of English *mow*.

Comment: Would that be a better work-around?                           "...................................                            Replete with a revolution of wrath / 
By those who fear no reprisal nor aftermath"

Comment: Your meaning is much clearer now—but the rhythm of the lines is somewhat the worse for wear, in case you're concerned about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word *aftermath* in this way. However, a better word might be *reprisal*:

> **reprisal** (n): something that is done to hurt or punish someone who has hurt you or done something bad to you

Comment: Would that be a better work-around?: "................................... Replete with a revolution of wrath / By those who fear no reprisal nor aftermath"

Comment: That doesn't rhyme!